# How to retrieve a recent list of trashed files using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have recently deleted quite a number of files in Google Drive, and they were moved to the trash. I would like to permanently delete them, but the files in the Trash can't be sorted by Deleted Date, but only Modified Date (which is not updated upon delete).

Therefore, I would like to leverage the Google Drive API to enumerate the trash and determine the date it was trashed, to find the set of files I would like to subsequently permanently delete.

From what I can gather, there is a file property which indicates if it has been trashed, but not the date.

I tried searching for this answer, but it's not easy to find, if it is possible. Is anyone familiar with this area of the API?

Is there a better strategy than what I am attempting?

Comment: Looking at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/, it would seem there is no way to retrieve a date associated with trashing (virtual folder) a file (let alone any date for movement to other real folders). It would be nice for the Google Drive API to include this.

Comment: This looks promising: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list. I'm not sure if it's listing files which were moved to trash. I'm hoping Changes are  different to Revisions. I'm looking for a definition of Change now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly using https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list, you can retrieve your most recent file/folder changes. This would seem to list those changes for folder movements as well as trashed files.

**Getting the data:**

1. Get a page token from - https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken
2. Put that token into - https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list, with page size of 500, includeRemoved on true, and select all fields with the fields editor link button.
3. You will see no results, because you are using the most recent page token. You need to manually reduce the page token until the returned changes.time is before the desired date range. (There is no filter for this in the query). Once you have established the correct page token, continue with the steps below.
4. Before Executing, open the Developer Tools (I was using Chrome) and view the Network section
5. Look for a transfer name staring with "changes?pageToken=...", and select it, copy the Response to Notepad++
6. Note the nextPageToken field, and update the requested page token, repeating step 5 until the nextPageToken not longer advances.

I used http://www.jsonquerytool.com/ to paste the data from notepad++ and to query out and find the relevant fileids.

**Querying the data for IDs** (for each of the results returned):

1. Paste the JSON into the JSON section
2. Select JSPath Query Type
3. Use this query to double-check document name ".changes{.file.trashed === true}.file.name"
4. Use this query to get ID list to keep ".changes{.file.trashed === true}.file.id"
5. Copy Results to Notepad++

**Permanent Deleting**

If you have a small amount of FileIDs (< 100), you may wish to manually run them through https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/delete, and optionally check them with https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get on each manual iteration.

**Automation**

Obviously, if you're dealing with more data it would make sense to write a Script or App to accomplish the above. But at least you can see it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

Using Todd's detailed answer, I wrote a Python script to achieve this. It's published on GitHub ([cfbao/google-drive-trash-cleaner](https://github.com/cfbao/google-drive-trash-cleaner)).

E.g. to view items trashed in the last 30 days, run
`python cleaner.py -v -d 30`
or
`cleaner.exe -v -d 30` on Windows

---

#### Edit:

Oops! big mistake!
`clean -v -d 30` shows you files trashed *more than* 30 days ago.

If you want to see files trashed in the last 30 days, run `clean -v -d 0` and see all trashed files sorted by their trash date.

Or you can modify my script so `-d 30` means "in the last 30 days". Shouldn't be too big a modification.