# Delete and Rename events in google drive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am working on a feature for our webapp where we create google drive files from our server

```js
Drive service =  getServiceForLoginUser();

com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
fileMetadata.setTitle(getDefaultName());
fileMetadata.setMimeType(APPLICATION_VND_GOOGLE_APPS_DRIVE_SDK);
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.Thumbnail thumbnail = buildThumbnail(driveType);
fileMetadata.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
        
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File googleFile = service.files().insert(fileMetadata)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
```

I have configured Drive UI Integration  to trigger New and Open URL flows from google drive.I have also published a chrome app with following manifest.

```html
"name" : "classflowtest",
  "version" : "3.5",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "icons": {
  "128": "icon_128.png"
   },
  "description" : "description_text",
  "container" : "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
  "api_console_project_id" : "146081768739",
  "gdrive_mime_types": {
    "http://drive.google.com/intents/opendrivedoc": [
   {
     "type": ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "html","application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.png",
     "application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.jpg","application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.gif","application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.html"],
     "href": "https://mywebappurl",
     "title" : "Open",
     "disposition" : "window"
   }
    ]
  },
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
    "web_url" : "mywebappurl"
    }
  }
```

So now I can trigger New and Open flows  in drive successfully. In New flow I create first a resource in our db and then I create a file in google drive from my application server. So every entry I create in google drive has a representation in our db as well. My issue is now if I rename or delete the file in google drive how do I get those events so that I can make the necessary changes in our DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [`Changes: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list) if it can help you. It will lists all the changes in your drive. But is is difficult to filter the results. To get the deleted files, you must specify the `includeRemoved` parameter to true. So it is easier to get the files if you know its `fileID` before you rename or delete it.

I found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937315/google-drive-api-changes-list-getting-the-original-id-of-a-deleted-file) that someone use [Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/) to solve this problem.

For more information, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803290/how-to-retrieve-a-recent-list-of-trashed-files-using-google-drive-api).