# Info on Document has vanished

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I accidently deleted a google doc and it does not give me the option to Restore  prior version and i cant find it in trash folder either?

restore prior version not working

Comment: Your question is off topic to Stack Overflow.  Please use the Google Docs Community at:  [https://support.google.com](https://support.google.com/docs/threads?hl=en&thread_filter=(category:docs_docs))

Comment: Have you read [How to retrieve a recent list of trashed files using Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34803290/1330560)? There might be something here to help find your file.